# Replace a text within single quotes with another string using sed(just a first occurrence of regex)

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file with the following content:

```
$ cat file.txt
CREATE COLLATION public.collation123 (provider = libc, locale = 'fr-FR');  
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_1 (provider = libc, locale = 'bas');  
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_test (provider = libc, locale = 'fr-FR');
```

I want to replace the **first occurrence** of `locale = 'fr-FR'` with `locale = 'fr_FR.utf8'`.

After replacing, the file should have the following content:

```
$cat file.txt
CREATE COLLATION public.collation123 (provider = libc, locale = 'fr_FR.utf8');  
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_1 (provider = libc, locale = 'bas');  
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_test (provider = libc, locale = 'fr-FR');
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed, you can use the special two-address form `0,/regexp/` to restrict a substitution command to a range up to and including the first instance:

```
$ cat file.txt
CREATE COLLATION public.collation123 (provider = libc, locale = 'fr-FR');
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_1 (provider = libc, locale = 'bas');
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_test (provider = libc, locale = 'fr-FR');

$ sed "0,/'fr-FR'/s//'fr_FR.utf8'/" file.txt
CREATE COLLATION public.collation123 (provider = libc, locale = 'fr_FR.utf8');
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_1 (provider = libc, locale = 'bas');
CREATE COLLATION public.collation_test (provider = libc, locale = 'fr-FR');
```

The empty pattern on the LHS of the `s/pattern/replacement` causes it to re-use the previous pattern from the address.

Of course, if you know that you only want to make the substitution in the first line, you can use the simpler `"1s/'fr-FR'/'fr_FR.utf8'/"`